# Building EmguCV on OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: mono, emgucv

I would really appreciate your help with an installation error. I've been trying to figure this out for days and can't find the answer online. Also, I need to use the EMGUCV wrapper for my work, and cannot use OpenCVsharp or other .net wrappers for opencv.

I am using OSX 10.6.8, I have installed mono/cmake and have followed the instructions in the [wiki](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#OSX) for the trunk version. I execute the following command, but the package fails to configure. I don't know how to interpret the output. Have also asked on the EmguCV forum, but not getting a lot of views there.

Thanks,
Rishi

```
cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=i386 -DBUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT:BOOL=FALSE -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=FALSE -DBUILD_TESTS:BOOL=FALSE -DBUILD_DOCS:BOOL=FALSE -DBUILD_JPEG=TRUE -DBUILD_PNG=TRUE -DBUILD_TIFF=TRUE .


-- Found csc: /usr/bin/gmcs
-- Found gacutil: /usr/bin/gacutil
-- Found al: /usr/bin/al
-- Found resgen: /usr/bin/resgen
-- Extracting Emgu CV svn version, please wait...
-- Emgu CV SVN VERSION: 1661
-- Building 32bit library
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 42 (402)
-- Extracting svn version, please wait...
-- SVNVERSION: svn:8208
-- Could NOT find Jasper (missing: JASPER_LIBRARIES JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- checking for module 'libavcodec'
-- package 'libavcodec' not found
-- checking for module 'libavformat'
-- package 'libavformat' not found
-- checking for module 'libavutil'
-- package 'libavutil' not found
-- checking for module 'libswscale'
-- package 'libswscale' not found
-- checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
-- package 'libdc1394-2' not found
-- checking for module 'libdc1394'
-- package 'libdc1394' not found
-- CUDA detected: 4.1
-- CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_11,code=sm_11;-gencode;arch=compute_12,code=sm_12;-gencode;arch=compute_13,code=sm_13;-gencode;arch=compute_20,code=sm_20;-gencode;arch=compute_20,code=sm_21;-gencode;arch=compute_20,code=compute_20
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.0 =====================================
-- Version control: svn:8208
-- 
-- Platform:
-- Host: Darwin 10.8.0 i386
-- CMake: 2.8.8
-- CMake generator: Unix Makefiles
-- CMake build tool: /usr/bin/make
-- 
-- C/C++:
-- Built as dynamic libs?: YES
-- C++ Compiler: /usr/bin/c++ (ver 4.2.1)
-- C++ flags (Release): -Wall -pthread -O3 -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -DNDEBUG
-- C++ flags (Debug): -Wall -pthread -g -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -ggdb3
-- C Compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- C flags (Release): -Wall -pthread -O3 -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -DNDEBUG
-- C flags (Debug): -Wall -pthread -g -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -ggdb3
-- Linker flags (Release): 
-- Linker flags (Debug): 
-- 
-- OpenCV modules:
-- To be built: calib3d contrib core features2d flann gpu highgui imgproc legacy ml nonfree objdetect photo stitching ts video videostab
-- Disabled by user: python
-- Disabled by dependency: -
-- Unavailable: androidcamera java
-- 
-- GUI: 
-- Cocoa: YES
-- OpenGL support: NO
-- 
-- Media I/O: 
-- ZLib: /usr/lib/libz.dylib (ver 1.2.3)
-- JPEG: libjpeg (ver 62)
-- PNG: build (ver 1.5.9)
-- TIFF: build (ver 42)
-- JPEG 2000: build (ver 1.900.1)
-- OpenEXR: NO
-- OpenNI: NO
-- OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules: NO
-- 
-- Video I/O: QTKit
-- FFMPEG: NO
-- codec: NO
-- format: NO
-- util: NO
-- swscale: NO
-- gentoo-style: NO
-- 
-- Other third-party libraries:
-- Use IPP: NO
-- Use TBB: NO
-- Use Cuda: YES (ver 4.1)
-- Use Eigen: NO
-- Use Clp: NO
-- 
-- NVIDIA CUDA:
-- Use CUFFT: YES
-- Use CUBLAS: NO
-- NVIDIA GPU arch: 11 12 13 20 21
-- NVIDIA PTX archs: 11 12 13 20 21
-- NVIDIA GPU features: 11 12 13 20 20 20
-- 
-- Python:
-- Interpreter: /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python (ver 2.7.2)
-- 
-- Tests and samples:
-- Tests: NO
-- Performance tests: NO
-- Examples: NO
-- 
-- Install path: /usr/local
-- 
-- cvconfig.h is in: /Users/rawatenator/emgucv
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
CMake Warning at opencv/CMakeLists.txt:973 (message):
The source directory is the same as binary directory. "make clean" may
damage the source tree


-- WITH CVBLOB: ON
-- Could NOT find TIFF (missing: TIFF_LIBRARY) (found version "3.8.2")
-- CVEXTERN: ZLIB found.
-- Skipping GEOTIFF
-- CPACK_GENERATOR: Bundle
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CUDA_nvcuvid_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
linked by target "opencv_gpu" in directory /Users/rawatenator/emgucv/opencv/modules/gpu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library is missing and it looks like its only available for windows.

CUDA_nvcuvid_LIBRARY
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html

if you just want to compile then do: "
ccmake -G "Unix makefiles" .."

and disable  following flag: "with_cuda"

that works for me