# Compiling OpenCV Source Code for 64 bit (Mac)

Tags: opencv, 64-bit

I'm having some problems while trying to compile 64 bit OpenCV libraries. This is what I've done so far:

1. Got the source code using svn
2. In the `opencv` I have `mkdir build` then `cd build`
3. `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64 -D CMAKE_C_FLAGS=-m64 -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-m64 ..`

This then leaves me with the output (below), which worries me because a number of packages are not found. I have tried disabling the `WITH_CUDA` flag as suggest in this post [Building EmguCV on OSX Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342682/building-emgucv-on-osx-snow-leopard) but it doesn't seem to help.

```
-- Extracting svn version, please wait...
-- SVNVERSION:  svn:9029
-- checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   package 'libdc1394-2' not found
-- checking for module 'libdc1394'
--   package 'libdc1394' not found
-- checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   package 'libavcodec' not found
-- checking for module 'libavformat'
--   package 'libavformat' not found
-- checking for module 'libavutil'
--   package 'libavutil' not found
-- checking for module 'libswscale'
--   package 'libswscale' not found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - not found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sphinx
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.9 =====================================
-- Version control:                 svn:9029
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Darwin 11.4.0 i386
--     CMake:                       2.8.8
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++
--     C++ flags (Release):         -m64   -O3 -DNDEBUG 
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -m64   -g 
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/gcc
--     C flags (Release):           -m64   -O3 -DNDEBUG 
--     C flags (Debug):             -m64   -g 
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core imgproc flann highgui features2d calib3d ml video objdetect contrib nonfree legacy gpu photo python stitching ts videostab
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 androidcamera java
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT 4.x:                      NO
--     Cocoa:                       YES
--     OpenGL support:              NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.6)
--     JPEG:                        build (ver 62)
--     PNG:                         build (ver 1.5.9)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.1)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       codec:                     NO
--       format:                    NO
--       util:                      NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       gentoo-style:              NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     QuickTime:                   NO
--     QTKit:                       YES
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     NO
--     Use TBB:                     NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use Clp:                     NO
-- 
--   Python:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python (ver 2.7.1)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (ver 2.7.1)
--     numpy:                       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include (ver 1.5.1)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/site-packages
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Build Documentation:         NO
--     Sphinx:                      NO
--     PdfLaTeX compiler:           /usr/texbin/pdflatex
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     Examples:                    NO
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/build
```

If I then try `make -j8` I get something that starts off like this and goes on fo a while:

```
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] [  1%] [  1%] [  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/adler32.c.o
Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/compress.c.o
Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/crc32.c.o
Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/pngerror.c.o
Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/png.c.o
Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/deflate.c.o
[  1%] [  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_cm.c.o
Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcapimin.c.o
In file included from /Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/3rdparty/libpng/pngerror.c:19:
/Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/3rdparty/libpng/pngpriv.h:45:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/3rdparty/libpng/pngpriv.h:127,
                 from /Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/3rdparty/libpng/pngerror.c:19:
/Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/3rdparty/libpng/png.h:442:26: error: setjmp.h: No such file or directory
/Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/3rdparty/libpng/png.h:450:24: error: time.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/3rdparty/libpng/png.c:14:
/Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/3rdparty/libpng/pngpriv.h:45:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/3rdparty/libpng/pngpriv.h:127,
                 from /Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/3rdparty/libpng/png.c:14:
/Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/3rdparty/libpng/png.h:442:26: error: setjmp.h: No such file or directory
/Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/3rdparty/libpng/png.h:450:24: error: time.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/3rdparty/zlib/zlib.h:34,
                 from /Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/3rdparty/zlib/compress.c:9:
/Users/Dash/Documents/SmartServices/AirLink/ProjectGhost/myOpencv/trunk/opencv/build/3rdparty/zlib/zconf.h:403:48: error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
```

**INSTRUCTIONS**

1. Download the zip from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv
2. When you unzip it you should be left with a folder called 'opencv-master', cd into it.
3. mkdir build
4. cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON ..
5. make
6. sudo make install

Comment: Did you solve this? I met exactly the same issue.

Comment: I think things ended up working for me...its been so long so I don't really recall much. To build OpenCV try the instructions I added to the question. Actually I should probably test it out before I put the instructions up...I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Not sure how much the instruction are going to help (hey seem obvious)...but i tried them now and it seemed to go smoothly. Let me know what problems you encounter on the way.

Comment: Thanks ! But i still get errors under your instruction. Fortunately, i  install it successfully use **brew install opencv** (With a lot of pain). Thanks again !

Comment: @MrROY - unfortunately brew does a crappy job installing openCV. No CUDA, no CLP support, etc. You have to babysit brew to make it install everything.